# How to match column data with row data using number in the column and row names?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Hi I have this set of MySQL table:

```
LOT_LOCATION,  Zone Attribute,  Voltage_1,         Current_1,         Voltage_2,         Current_2, Voltage_3, Current_3, Voltage_4, Current_4, Voltage_5, Current_5, Voltage_6, Current_6
'SGHAST.0035', '1',            '3.6V, 1.94V, V',   '0.02A, 0.08A, A', '0.03V, 0.01V, V', '0.0A, 0.03A, A', '3.62V, 1.95V, V', '0.0A, 0.09A, A', 'V, V, V', 'A, A, A', 'V, V, V', 'A, A, A', 'V, V, V', 'A, A, A'
'SGHAST.0035', '3',            '3.6V, 1.94V, V',   '0.02A, 0.08A, A', '0.03V, 0.01V, V', '0.0A, 0.03A, A', '3.62V, 1.95V, V', '0.0A, 0.09A, A', 'V, V, V', 'A, A, A', 'V, V, V', 'A, A, A', 'V, V, V', 'A, A, A'
```

What I want to do is to match Voltage_1 and Current_1 since they contain the number 1 to Zone Attribute that has 1, and Voltage_3 and Current_3 since they contain the number 3 to Zone Attribute that has 3, by creating a column Voltage and Current that contain all these values together in the same 2 columns (and not separate columns as above).

Like this:

```
LOT_LOCATION,  Zone Attribute, Voltage,           Current
'SGHAST.0035', '1',            '3.6V, 1.94V, V',  '0.02A, 0.08A, A'
'SGHAST.0035', '3',            '3.62V, 1.95V, V', '0.0A, 0.09A, A'


Is there any way to solve this? Any help is appreciated thanks!
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d5f68f8a1b9f40c58944b676c70c9b05 (with the table, not the answer)

Comment: You can use UNION ALL, see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=53e2f45e657ef30db3c618ba6c8d0a05)

Comment: @Luuk the thing is i need to match with the zone attribute value number so i cannot just union all

Comment: Agree with @Luuk, UNION all looks fine. For zone you can use pseudo-column. Refer - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cf561f0fafb0d764ba4106b711675c98

Comment: @GQS: What is the problem with it? If you look at the query in the dbfiddle you should not that each part (before/after the union all) is different, and the WHERE-clause is different too.  How many `zone attribute` do you have?

Comment: @Luuk ah sorry managed to understand what u were telling me thank you so much!